# Count the number of hours within a certain range on excel

Tags: excel

I am wanting to enhance the functionality of my time sheet. I want to calculate if a person's hours falls into a range, and if so, count how many hours. For example:

A user clocks in on their time sheet:
`Tuesday: 05:00 - 04:00` i.e. - They worked 23 hours.

From the above time, I want to count how many hours they have worked between the time range `19:30 - 07:30`.

Manually calculating this works out at 9.5 hours - or 09:30.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is working for me in all the cases I've tested:

Data cells:

> A1: Range start | B1: Range end
>
> A2: Clock In       | B2: Clock out

Formula:

```
=IF(B2<A1,0,IF(A2>B1,0,IF(A2<A1,IF(B2>B1,B1-A1,B2-A1),IF(B2>B1,B1-A2,B2-A2))))
```

The result is in days, so if you want it in hours, just multiply by 24.

```
=IF(B2<A1,0,IF(A2>B1,0,IF(A2<A1,IF(B2>B1,B1-A1,B2-A1),IF(B2>B1,B1-A2,B2-A2))))*24
```

If the times span more than one day, it's crucial for this to work that the cells include the date. In Excel, if you just enter the time, its (fake) date is 00/01/1900, so for the ending times to have the appropriate date, I specified the next day: 01/01/1900. Therefore, if you only have the time, you will have to do this as well.

But if you get a full `DateTime` from, for example, a database, then you won't have this issue, but you will have to modify the range cells to have the corresponding dates, or modify the clock cells to convert the date back to 00/01/1900, depending on your scenario. Please give some more details if you need help with this.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, when a user is entering their `Clock In` and `Clock Out` times, they only enter the time. What I've tried to do is concatenate this time with the date in another cell, to make it 'look' like a long date, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way of having `Clock In` at 01/01/2014 TIME, and then, if `Clock Out` is over 12pm, to knock it over a date?!

Comment: I think maybe the best option is to use an auxiliary cell, in which you add 1 to the `Clock Out` time. This way you are adding 1 day to that time, therefore making it 01/01/1900. But first you must be sure that the time actually belongs to the following day. If they type 23:30, I guess you shouldn't want to add anything. So you should decide what is your threshold (12pm perhaps? Remember that 12pm is noon and 12am is midnight).
For example, you could place this in C2: `=IF(B2>0.5,B2,B2+1)` and use that column instead.
Do people have all kind of time shifts or only through midnight?

Comment: Right, I think I understand. Thank you for your reply again. Yes, unfortunately! They could start at 5am one morning, and, for example, work until 22:00pm that same day. Or vice versa, start at 22:00pm on 01/01/2014 and work until 5am which is 02/01/2014.

Comment: Could they work more than 24 hs? If not, then you can use this formula in C2 instead: `=IF(B2-A2<=0,B2+1,B2)` This way, the work hours will always be > 0 and <= 24.
If they can work more than 24hs but not less than, say, 1 hour, you can use this other formula: `=IF(B2-A2<=1/24,B2+1,B2)` This way, the work hours will always be > 1 and <= 25.
If someone can work 3 hours and another one 27 hours, then you have no way to difference them if the person does not enter the date in the spreadsheet.

Comment: No, definitely no more than 24 hours, however, for example, their 12 hour shift could go into the next day. I think I'll be stuck using this method as they don't enter the date into their timesheets!! How inconvenient. I think I'm trying to automate a process that has to be manual!

Comment: But with this last formula I commented, you don't have to manually edit anything. They type the `Clock Out` time, the next column (hidden) does that calculation (adds 1 day to time if it's earlier than the `Clock In`) and then you use the formula from my answer (or jbarker2160's, it works as well, just remember to do *24 if you want the result in hours).

Comment: I understand, but on the initial `Clock In` time, I would also need a date adding (preferably in a hidden column?), wouldn't I? I tried this, but it didn't return anything - `="01/01/2014"&"  "&TEXT(B8, "hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: You don't need to add anything. As per my first comment, if you enter the time alone, the cell's "hidden" date is 00/01/1900. As long as you don't show the date anywhere, it's no problem at all. If you need today's date, you can do something like `=B2+TODAY()` (it's better to add rather than concatenate strings). These details depend on how you will organize your spreadsheet. For example, if you have one per day, you can hardcode the date on a specific cell and add that to every user-entered time cell. Perhaps if you explain a little more the scenario, I could think of a better workaround. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andrew, I appreciate it! Right, I now have a working model right up until midnight. Once it goes into the next day, it returns 0. I know that I need to somehow implement the formula `=IF(B2-A2<=0,B2+1,B2)`, but where does this go? Currently, I have your long, initial formula in `C2`. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Ben. Sorry for the delay. This how would do it:
A2: Clock In time.
B2: Clock Out time.
C2: `=IF(B2-A2<=0,B2+1,B2)` (this adds 1 day if out < in).
D2: `=IF(C2<$A$1,0,IF(A2>$B$1,0,IF(C2<$B$1,C2,$B$1)-IF(A2>$A$1,A2,$A$1)))*24`


Use this if D2 has a Numeric format. If you want a `hh:mm` format, remove the `*24`.
Finally, you can hide the column `C`.
Note that the references to the range cells are now absolute, so you can copy the formula without problems.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, no need to apologise, it's you who's helping me out! Unfortunately, D2 is still returning 0, for example - `Clock In` - 08:30, `Clock Out` - 02:00. C2 is picking up that it's a day later, so that cell is definitely working.

Comment: It is working now, I had to change B1's date to the following day. Many thanks for your help @Andrew.

Comment: Oh, yes, that was a very important detail. Good to know it's working now. :) Thanks for accepting my answer. :)

Comment: One small comment (I wish I could have made it in the question but I don't have enough reputation): your manually calculated work hours should be 8.5 and not 9.5, right?

Answer (score 1):

## Formula:

`=IF(ClockOut<RangeStart,0,IF(ClockIn>RangeEnd,0,IF(ClockOut<RangeEnd,ClockOut,RangeEnd)-IF(ClockIn>RangeStart,ClockIn,RangeStart)))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply jbarker2160, unfortunately, on the same example above, it returns 0.

Comment: You'll have to include the date as part of the calculation.

Comment: @jbarker2160 - Given that the start time may be greater than the end time due to crossing over midnight it is a good idea to add in a `Boolean` like '(ClockOut+(ClockOut<ClockIn))-ClockIn`. Excel will interpret a `TRUE` as *1* (a day) and add it to the *ClockOut* time before the subtraction.

Comment: Could you provide an example please jbarket2160. The `ClockIn` and `ClockOut` time is referenced in 2 cells - 19:30 and 07:30.

Comment: I add the date to the `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd`, like this `01/01/2014  19:30:00`, `02/01/2014  07:30:00` but the hours are still returning 0?

Comment: Did you also add the dates to the `ClockIn` and `ClockOut`?

Comment: Yes, they they're part of the time sheet itself, so I just reference the cells.

Comment: You need to use ClockIn Date + ClockIn Time, ClockOut Date + ClockOut Time, etc.  I've thoroughly tested with a huge range of dates and times for all parameters and it works perfectly for me.